# How to manually reset the data in a step of a formtool wizard?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-formtools

I have a wizard with several steps organized as follow:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6
          |         ^
          |         |
           --> 5 ---
```

where step 6 is just a review of the data in previous steps. Steps 4 and 5 are mutually exclusive.

If a user travels the form 1,2,3,4,6 and then decides to use 5 instead of 4 I want to be able to reset the data in step 4.
How can I manually reset the data already stored for step 4 (or any step) of the wizard?

Comment: Inside the `WizardView`, `self.storage` is the storage object for all the data and `self.storage.set_step_data(step, data)` will set the data of a specific step to `data`. So `self.storage.set_step_data('4', {})` would reset the data for step 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really documented in django-formtools, but you'll find that the `WizardView` has a property `self.storage` which is an instance of `BaseStorage` (in 'formtools.wizard.storage.base').

`self.storage.data` is a dictionary of all the stored data. It's a bit dangerous to manipulate this dictionary directly, better use the method `self.storage.set_step_data(step, data)` to change the data for specific step:

```
self.storage.set_step_data('4', {})
```

will empty the data for step '4'.

Note: If you're also uploading files, you should remove them, which is a bit tricky, because `self.storage.set_step_files(step, files)` doesn't do anything if `files` is empty (`{}`). Look at that method to either override it or see how to remove the files from the data dictionary.

Comment: Ah you should probably keep the management form data. Take a look at the data in your debugger. It’s the TOTAL_FORMS, INITIAL_FORMS etc fields

Comment: I think the problem is that the step uploads a file, just as you already mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I managed to reset `self.storage['step_files']` just by doing `self.storage['step_files']['4'] = {}` but you are right. There is a `[ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with]` error. How and where should I keep the values for the formset?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments to the answer of dirkgroten I have a `step` in the form wizard that is a `formset`. For this particular step using `self.storage.set_step_data(step, {})` results in an error every time the `step` or the information for the `step` is used because, as dirkgroten pointed out in his comments, information for the `ManagementForm` is missing after manually setting the data for `step`.

Therefore, I end up simply removing the `key` - `value` pair for `step` from `self.storage`. By doing this, I get the normal behavior of the form wizard e.g. `self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(step)` returns `None` if `step` is not in `self.storage` and the `formset` is correctly initiated when using the `step` after removing `step` from `self.storage`.

To delete `step` from `self.storage` I used the `process_step` method in the `formwizard`.

```
def process_step(self, form):
    """ Process the form after step data is submitted and validated by jQuery.  """
 #--> Get form prefix
    prefix = form.prefix
 #--> Action per step
    if prefix == 'e':
     #--> Set previous experiment
        try:
            exp_save = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('e')
            if exp_save is None:
                pass
            else:
                exp_save = exp_save['e_exp'].id
        except KeyError:
            exp_save = None
     #--> Get selected experiment
        exp_sel = form.cleaned_data['e_exp'].id
     #--> Compare and delete steps if needed
        if exp_save is None:
            pass
        else:           
            if exp_sel == exp_save:
                pass
            else:
                for stepN in self.delStep[exp_sel]:
                 #--> self.delStep is a dict with the steps to be deleted for each exp_sel
                    if stepN in self.storage.data['step_data'].keys():
                     #--> Remove the key-value pair from data and files if there is already something to delete
                        del self.storage.data['step_data'][stepN]
                        del self.storage.data['step_files'][stepN]
                    else:
                        pass                
    else:
        pass
 #--> Return as implemented in the base class
    return self.get_form_step_data(form)
#---
```

This of course, as also mentioned by dirkgroten, does not remove leftover files.